# How to use SectionIndexer on dates

Tags: android, android-listview

I have been searching on ways to use the SectionIndexer on dates in my listView. I would like to show the "short date" when fast scrolling my list. I saw a post from a couple years ago with a guy saying he had it working and he had a different issue, but sadly he didn't post any code for his method.

I figure I will have to do something to my custom ArrayAdapter but I am not really sure what, anyone have any ideas of where I can look for something like this?

Thanks,
-Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so here is what I ended up doing to get it to work properly, just in case someone else in the future is looking for something similar.

```
private class TransactionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaction> implements SectionIndexer
{
    private ArrayList<Transaction> items;
    private Context context;
    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> dateIndexer;
    String[] sections;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Transaction> items)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

        this.dateIndexer = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
        int size = items.size();
        String prDate = " ";

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            Transaction tr = items.get(x);
            Calendar date = tr.getDate();
            String month = date.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
            String year = String.valueOf(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String shortDate = month + " " + year;

            if( !shortDate.equals(prDate))
            {
                this.dateIndexer.put(shortDate, x);
                prDate = shortDate;
            }
        }

        Set<String> sectionDates = this.dateIndexer.keySet();

        // create a list from the set to sort
        ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<String>(sectionDates);
        this.sections = new String[sectionList.size()];
        sectionList.toArray(this.sections);
    }

    public int getPositionForSection(int section) 
    {
        return dateIndexer.get(this.sections[section]);
    }

    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public Object[] getSections() 
    {
        return this.sections;
    }
}
```

I found the answer in a combination of two places:

1. This tutorial helped me with the initial implementation of the SectionIndexter: [Android ListView with fastscroll and section index](http://twistbyte.com/tutorial/android-listview-with-fast-scroll-and-section-index)
2. This post fixed an issue I had with the HashMap changing my ordering of my array, it suggested using a LinkedHashMap instead. [is the Java HashMap keySet() iteration order consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882762/is-the-java-hashmap-keyset-iteration-order-consistent)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/simple-section-adapter) library. This is the Simpliest Section Adapter available for Android's ListView. It works with list adapters that you already have. No project specific dependencies. Just include the latest jar or the sources to your Android project.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the link. It works as advertised, but not quite what I was looking for. I don't really want the breaks in my data like your library is showing on my dates, what I really want is just the fastscroll option like I get when using an alphabetindexer but showing the short dates (Jan 2012, Feb 2012 etc). In the default alphabetindexer it pops up a floating "A", "B", "C" etc as the user uses the thumb scroll. Can something like this be done with your library without the breaks using the layout header?