# Iteration order of java.util.HashMap.values()

Tags: java

Is it guaranteed that keys and values in standard implementations of `java.util.Map` are returned in the same order? For example, if map contains mapping `x1 -> y1` and `x2 -> y2`, then if `keySet()` iteration yields `x1, x2`, is it guaranteed that `values()` iteration will yield `y1, y2` and not `y2, y1`? I haven't seen anywhere guaranteed that this is true, but it seems to work. Could anyone give confirm or deny this premise and give counterexample?

```
public class MapsTest {
    @Test
    public void hashMapKeysAndValuesAreInSameOrder() {
        assertKeysAndValuesAreInSameOrder(new HashMap<>());
    }

    @Test
    public void treeMapKeysAndValuesAreInSameOrder() {
        assertKeysAndValuesAreInSameOrder(new TreeMap<>());
    }

    private void assertKeysAndValuesAreInSameOrder(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        Random random = new Random();
        IntStream.range(0, 100000).map(i -> random.nextInt()).forEach(i -> map.put(i, i));
        assertEquals(new ArrayList<>(map.keySet()), new ArrayList<>(map.values()));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can rely on it since the documentation of `values()` does not mention this point.

Comment: I guess this feature is part of public contract despite the fact that it's not documented. By the way, I just remembered Linus Torvald's posts "We never break userspace".

Answer (score 6):

From the doc of [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html),

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

If you look at its [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java), you will find out that once you call `put()`, eventually `hash` is calculated, `entry object` is created and added into a `bucket array`. I have over simplified the purpose of the code just to explain what happens behind the scene.

If you want guaranteed order, use [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) or [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) depending on your requirements

Also check,

[Difference between HashMap, LinkedHashMap and TreeMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-treemap)

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question. I gave it a shot. and it seems the RELATIVE ordering of the keys remains in sync with the values.

```
import java.util.*;
public class MapClass {
public static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

  public static void main (String[] args){
    map.put("first", 1);
    map.put("second", 2);
    map.put("third", 3);
    map.put("fourth", 4);
    map.put("fifth", 5);

    System.out.println(map.keySet());
    System.out.println(map.values());

    map.put("sixth", 6);
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
    System.out.println(map.values());

    map.remove("first");
    System.out.println(map.keySet());
    System.out.println(map.values());
  }
}
```

I get:

```
[third, fifth, fourth, first, second]
[3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
[sixth, third, fifth, fourth, first, second]
[6, 3, 5, 4, 1, 2]
[sixth, third, fifth, fourth, second]
[6, 3, 5, 4, 2]
```

This simple example seems to show that while a `HashMap` will not preserve the order of insertion, it seems it does preserve the relative ordering of keys and values.

keyset() and values() does not guarantee any order though, but it seems [in practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882782/792238) that it'll return the same order for multiple invocations. As the comment on there says, even if you could rely on it, it's questionable whether you should.

Answer (score 3):

From the [HashMap docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

Comment: I saw this sentence but in my opinion it doesn't say anything about the relationship of order of keys() and values().

Comment: It could, but it doesn't. I wonder if anyone could give me an example.

Comment: I thought ConcurrentModificationException would be thrown. And these maps are not thread-safe, so concurrency is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.values%28%29, I'd guess it works because both the KeyIterator and ValueIterator extend HashIterator.

But that's only if you don't change the HashMap in the mean time, e.g. adding and removing items between calling keySet() and values(), because that can change the bucket size, and the HashIterator will behave differently.

Comment: Tests still pass with `...forEach(i -> {
   map.put(i, i);
   map.values();
  }`

Comment: If you do System.out.println(map.keySet());, then add a 100000 items, remove all 100000 again, and then print the map.values(), you might have different results...

Comment: Same story with `TreeMap`? All iterators extend `PrivateEntryIterator` http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/TreeMap.java#TreeMap.EntryIterator

Comment: A TreeMap is a SortedMap. So it's required to keep the same order over all it's iterators.  

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html
"The map is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time. This order is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views (returned by the entrySet, keySet and values methods). Several additional operations are provided to take advantage of the ordering. (This interface is the map analogue of SortedSet.)"

Comment: This post is about relative order of keys() and values(), not about absolute order of keys().