# Does java HashMap.entrySet() iterate through the HashMap in order of insertion?

Tags: java, hashmap

While iterating through the HashMap of Integer to String, suppose I insert values in the following order

```
HashMap<Integer, String> hash_map = new HashMap<>();
hash_map.put(0, "check");
hash_map.put(1, "ok");
hash_map.put(2, "what");
hash_map.put(4, "why");
```

When I iterate through the HashMap, using hash_map.entrySet(), will I iterate through it in order of insertion? Or will it be a random order?

Comment: order in hashmap as well as hash set is not ogranized by order of insertion.

Comment: From the [documentation of `HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html): "*This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.*"

Comment: I think this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882762/is-the-java-hashmap-keyset-iteration-order-consistent

Comment: You need `LinkedHashMap` to guarantee order.

Comment: What is the difference between keySet and entrySet?

Comment: @UddhavBhagat - `keySet` is the set of keys and `entrySet` is the set of entries (key=value pair).

Comment: @UddhavBhagat What does the **documentation** say the difference is? --- [`keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) *"Returns a Set view of the **keys** contained in this map"* with return type `Set<K>`. --- [`entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()) *"Returns a Set view of the **mappings** contained in this map"* with return type `Set<Entry<K,​V>>`.

Answer (score 2):

When you need a Map and you don't care about the order (when you iterate through it), then HashMap is the right choice.

If you want the order of insertion try **LinkedHashMap**

try reading this : https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/java-maps.php

Comment: I'm not getting the option to import the LinkedHashMap from java.util. Why is that?

Comment: Not sure maybe IDE issue.. but it should be there ```import java.util.LinkedHashMap;```