# How is the sequence decided when looping through map

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question about the sequence of hash map.  For example, in the following code:

```
public class MapEntrySetOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        String[] l = new String[]{"Entry", "Set", "HashMap", "Order"};
        for (String s : l) {
            map.putIfAbsent(s, s);
        }
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key:" + e.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is no order maintained in hashmap, but every time I print the keys thru a loop, there are all in same order, and the order is not from the beginning of the original list nor from the end of the original list:

```
key:Order
key:Entry
key:Set
key:HashMap
```

So how is the order decided. If it is in a random way, why every time I print they are the same result?

Comment: If it were random, it would be called `RandomMap`.

Comment: All that matters is that the coder using the HashMap understands that they cannot rely on the order. Maybe you can find your answer in the HashMap source code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is the Java HashMap keySet() iteration order consistent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882762/is-the-java-hashmap-keyset-iteration-order-consistent)

Comment: *why every time i print they are the same result?* try it on different java versions and you'll notice the difference. There is no guarantee of the order in a Hashmap

Answer (score 1):

Use HashMap for fast non-ordered Map

Use LinkedHashMap for order of adding to the Map

Use TreeMap for any order you wish (with Comparator implementation)

Also I think you have same order each time because you use `map.entrySet()` instead of `map.keySet()`

Answer (score 0):

`Hashmap` does not guarantee any order.
If you want ordered sequence use [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) instead.