# How to manage unique code in mobile application corresponding to each application user?

Tags: java, android, key, uniqueidentifier

Please recommend any method/best practice which takes unique data from phone, munches it and always produces the same key for given user on his/her device.

Comment: More explanation needed.

Comment: case 1 - User downloads a application on android phone , you need to sync up his data to cloud, without user creating a account either on phone or web

Comment: case 2 - User makes a payment on web - You want to give him a unique code which when he enters on mobile - his application gets some more goodies

Answer (score 0):

**1** You capture IMEI.
**2** You can capture Bluetooth UUID
**3** You can generate UUID or a random string and can associate it with device logically

Comment: Yes, I need recommendation for for the unique string generation algo/best practice etc., so that it is short and unique, just like url shorteners do with the URL

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string-in-java

Comment: thank you for the link, the requirement is like "Given a IMEI I always get UNIQUE code of length 5" and this code is unique across users

Comment: @dhaval You want to take a 15 or 16 digit IMEI and generate a 5 character code that will be guaranteed to be unique for all possible IMEI numbers?

Comment: @dave hmm , tuf one, okay IMEI was given as example so that it acts like a seed, when fed to a algorithm, generates a unique 5-7 digit alphanumeric code