# Free tool for text document creation with conditions

Tags: testing

I was assigned as a tester to create test data in this format

```
--|id(13603644000102161)|hrtime(2013-02-09T00:00:00.010+0100)-- 
Event-Timestamp=1360364400,                                     
NAS-Port Id=L2TP LNS 204639, 
Service-Type=Framed-User, 
NAS-Identifier=ba2-stlns-67, 
Tunnel-Server-Auth-Id= ba2-stlns-67, 
Tunnel-Type=L2TP, 
NAS-Port-Type=Virtual, 
Tunnel-Client-Endpoint= xxx.81.232.209, 
Acct-Session Id=FF10FFFF58031F5F-50FE2ADA, 
User-Name=uid@edunet.sk, NAS-Port=1862066337, 
Acct-Session-Time=1529998, 
Tunnel-Medium-Type=IPv4, 
Acct-Input-Octets=-277291554, 
Acct-Authentic=Radius, 
Tunnel-Client-Auth-Id= edunet, 
Framed-IP-Address=172.16.0.78, 
Acct-Status-Type=Interim-Update, 
Framed-IP-Netmask=255.255.255.255, 
Framed-Protocol=PPP, 
Calling-Station-Id=#/108778489/BB_WOLK-12 atm 1/1/09/60:1.32, 
Framed-Route=192.168.9.60/30 172.16.0.78, 
Acct-Output-Packets=66401591, 
NAS-IP-Address=213.81.255.165, 
Tunnel-Server-Endpoint= 87.197.192.235
```

For each of these attributes i have some condition which must be fullfiled. I am looking for a tool where can i enter regex or another condition and it will generate something like this...

Yes... it should be relative easy to code this in java but i have aprx. 50 types of log formats to consider.

Comment: Some password cracking tools have just such customizable generation capabilities. _I never used them though._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to generate text from a regex, see:

http://code.google.com/p/xeger/

[Generate a String that matches a RegEx in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627464/generate-a-string-that-matches-a-regex-in-python)

[Reversing a regular expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python)

[java use Regular Expressions to generate a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317073/java-use-regular-expressions-to-generate-a-string)

[Random Text generator based on regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274011/random-text-generator-based-on-regex)

[Generate a random string based on a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959850/generate-a-random-string-based-on-a-regular-expression)