# Validate order ids sent by google after android inapp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing

I have implemented the inapp billing which is working perfectly to my application and now I want to validate the correct order ids. Is there any method to check that I have received the correct order id and a valid order ids. Kindly tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what I have understood from your question check my below answer,
You have to store your order id either in your local database or server side database.

you can retrieve the information after user purchased the item, you can get response. you can store order id from that response in your database.

check this link for more information:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

you can verify that you can purchased correct product or not by using developer payload, check this links 
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613520/what-should-be-the-developer-payload-in-android-in-app-billing-v3-api/18650153#18650153) and [link2](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#orderId). After purchasing the product you can verify either user has purchased the same product or not.

Hope it will solve your query.

Comment: What if purchase is from play store instead of inapp . How to get order id ??