# Creating a random string with A-Z and 0-9 in Java

Tags: java, random

As the title suggest I need to create a random, 17 characters long, ID. Something like "`AJB53JHS232ERO0H1`". The order of letters and numbers is also random. I thought of creating an array with letters A-Z and a 'check' variable that randoms to `1-2`. And in a loop;

```
Randomize 'check' to 1-2.
If (check == 1) then the character is a letter.
Pick a random index from the letters array.
else
Pick a random number.
```

But I feel like there is an easier way of doing this. Is there?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string

Comment: you can put your letters and digits into an array and then randomly choose elements from it until you reach your desired size.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Here you can use my method for generating Random String

```
protected String getSaltString() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < 18) { // length of the random string.
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String saltStr = salt.toString();
        return saltStr;

    }
```

The above method from my bag using to generate a salt string for login purpose.

Comment: May I suggest to replace `StringBuffer` by a `StringBuilder`, no need to have a thread-safe impl. here

Comment: Or just create a `char[]` given that you know exactly how long it will be. No need to append anything. I'd also use `Random.nextInt` rather than calling `nextFloat` and multiplying it by the length.

Comment: Note that the average amount of numbers won't be the same as the amount of letters.

Comment: @RC. Yes. I'm using it in a servlet environment. So need it. Otherwise a StringBuilder

Comment: One thing to keep in mind if you use this is that, the Random class is sudo random and not a true random. Tried to use this to print 400 Strings to a file and found that it wasn't as random as I wanted. :(

Comment: @SharpIncTechAndProgramming have you tried it with SecureRandom ? Also to my knowledge (maybe I'm wrong) it would be better to provide the same instance of Random to all Strings generated.

Answer (score 123):

[`RandomStringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from Apache commons-lang might help:

```
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(17).toUpperCase()
```

---

**2017 update**: `RandomStringUtils` has been deprecated, you should now use [RandomStringGenerator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.html).

Comment: Consider updating the answer as Apache replaced it with `RandomStringGenerator` in commons-text.

Comment: You can also use `RandomStringUtils.random(length, useLetters, useNumbers)` where length is **int** while useLetters and useNumbers are **boolean** values.

Comment: Superb,Single line code,we require this type of codes.

Comment: @NeriaNachum where are you seeing that `RandomStringUtils` has been replaced/deprecated? I'm just seeing "RandomStringUtils is intended for simple use cases. For more advanced use cases consider using Apache Commons Text's RandomStringGenerator instead." [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)

Comment: Using RandomStringGenerator (from apachae common)  you can produce a random String of desired length. Following snippet will generate a String of length between 5 - 15 ( both inclusive)

//
char [][] pairs = {{'a','z'},{'A','Z'},{'0','9'}};
        RandomStringGenerator randomStringGenerator = new 
               RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
                .withinRange(pairs)
                .build();
       String randomString = randomStringGenerator.generate(5, 15);
//

Answer (score 21):

Three steps to implement your function:

**Step#1** You can specify a string, including the chars A-Z and 0-9.

Like.

```
 String candidateChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
```

**Step#2** Then if you would like to generate a random char from this candidate string. You can use

```
 candidateChars.charAt(random.nextInt(candidateChars.length()));
```

**Step#3** At last, specify the length of random string to be generated (in your description, it is 17).
Writer a for-loop and append the random chars generated in step#2 to StringBuilder object.

Based on this, here is an example

```
public class RandomTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        System.out.println (generateRandomChars (
                "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890", 17));
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param candidateChars the candidate chars
     * @param length the number of random chars to be generated
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static String generateRandomChars (String candidateChars, int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        Random random = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
            sb.append (candidateChars.charAt (random.nextInt (candidateChars
                    .length ())));
        }

        return sb.toString ();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do that with a for loop,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String aToZ="ABCD.....1234"; // 36 letter.
  String randomStr=generateRandom(aToZ);

}

private static String generateRandom(String aToZ) {
    Random rand=new Random();
    StringBuilder res=new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
       int randIndex=rand.nextInt(aToZ.length()); 
       res.append(aToZ.charAt(randIndex));            
    }
    return res.toString();
}
```