# Generate random codes in Client-Side of GWT

Tags: java, gwt, code-generation

I have created a java gwt application in which I want to verify user's email address from client side, is there any way to generate random 5 character code on client side?

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look here with Basic GWT white list classes :http://stackoverflow.com/a/20536597/1927832 , Haven't checked Random is is white list or not.

Comment: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Random.html

Comment: You may have a look at this project https://code.google.com/p/gwt-crypto/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you test with [Java Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) .You can simply get by it.

Here is useful formula for generating random numbers

> **(int)(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)**

So , you can generate 5 random numbers as like...

```
String randomCodes = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * (99999 - 1) + 1));
    while (randomCodes.length() < 5) {
            randomCodes = "0" + randomCodes;
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Random random = new Random();

for (int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    sb.append('a'+random.nextInt(26));
}
String code = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RandomStringUtils from the Apache Commons project,

RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5);

Comment: This will lead me to add an extra library which I don't want. Looking for some that Gwt provide on its own. Else the solutions provided by Tim is good just iteration would be the problem.