# Generate random emails with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

How can I generate random emails using Selenium with Java?

I was looking here in StackOverflow but I haven't found the answer to this.
I have tried with this, but it didn't help.

```java
public class registerClass{
     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        
       String baseUrl = " ";
       
       driver.get(baseUrl);
       driver.manage().window().maximize();
       driver.findElement(By.id("cboxClose")).click();
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[1]")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.id("register.firstName")).sendKeys("Karla");
       driver.findElement(By.id("register.paternalLastName")).sendKeys("Perez");
       driver.findElement(By.id("register.maternalLastName")).sendKeys("castro");
      
       driver.findElement(By.id("register.email")).sendKeys("castro9999@gmail.com");
     
       //driver.close();
       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Email addresses or real boxes?

Comment: If you just want to generate emails, selenium is not needed. Could do you add your code so far?

Comment: I added my code, i just want to generate a random email everytime that it runs

Comment: You just need random string generator in you code.

Comment: @karlaA I updated the answer below

Comment: If you write "I tried this" you should show it. That is why I undid your probably accidental edit. If you write "but it did not help" you should explain how exactly it did not help. Have a look at [ask]. Also, when you got answers, please be careful with changing the question, though I think this is not a problem in this case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need random string generator. This answer I stole from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536566/creating-a-random-string-with-a-z-and-0-9-in-java).

```
protected String getSaltString() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < 10) { // length of the random string.
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        return salt.toString();

    }
```

Call it as `getSaltString()+"@gmail.com"` in you code

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try to integrate it with selenium

Comment: Okay let me try it.

Comment: @karlaA just click on Right sign right to my answer.

Comment: Done. :) Thank you for helping me

Comment: An email shouldn't start with a digit, no?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a method for generating the unique id

```
 public static String getUniqueId() {
            return String.format("%s_%s", UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 5), System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
        }
```

And then use this method with the hostname which you need

```
 public static String generateRandomEmail() {
        return String.format("%s@%s", getUniqueId(), "yourHostName.com");
    }
```

**Another solution:**

Add dependency for `javafaker.Faker` [https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker](http://faker)

```
import com.github.javafaker.Faker;

public static String randomEmail() {
      Faker faker = new Faker();
      return faker.internet().emailAddress();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method

```
/**
 * @author mbn
 * @Date 05/10/2018
 * @Purpose This method will generate a random integer
 * @param length --> the length of the random emails we want to generate
 * @return method will return a random email String
 */
public static String generateRandomEmail(int length) {
    log.info("Generating a Random email String");
    String allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "1234567890" + "_-.";
    String email = "";
    String temp = RandomStringUtils.random(length, allowedChars);
    email = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - 9) + "@testdata.com";
    return email;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [MockNeat](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat). A simple example the library would be:

```
String email = mock.emails().val();
// Possible Output: icedvida@yahoo.com
```

Or if you want to generate emails from specific domains:

```
String corpEmail = mock.emails().domain("startup.io").val();
// Possible Output: tiptoplunge@startup.io
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for the random email generator.

```
 //randomestring() will return string of 8 chars

  import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

  public String randomestring()
  {
    String generatedstring=RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(8);
    return(generatedstring);
   }


  //Usage
   String email=randomestring()+"@gmail.com";

 //For Random Number generation 
////randomeNum() will return string of 4 digits

   public static String randomeNum() {
        String generatedString2 = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(4);
        return (generatedString2);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding a library, Generex is great for test data.
https://github.com/mifmif/Generex

Add this to your pom.xml if you are using maven, otherwise check the link above for other options.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mifmif</groupId>
        <artifactId>generex</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then:

```
// we have to escape @ for some reason, otherwise we get StackOverflowError
String regex = "\\w{10}\\@gmail\\.com"
driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddressInput"))
           .sendText(new Generex(regex).random());
```

It uses a regular expression to specify the format for the random generation. The regex above is generate 10 random word characters, append @gmail.com. If you want a longer username, change the number 10.

If you want to generate a random mobile number for say, Zimbabwe (where I live):

```
String regex = "2637(1|3|7|8)\\d{7}";
```

This library has saved me so many hours.

Comment: Executing your email regex as an example (which lacks a semi-colon at the end of first line btw), it causes a StackOverflowError. I was able to solve it by adding a \\ (double backslash) before the @

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it in Kotlin:

```
object EmailGenerator {
    private const val ALLOWED_CHARS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "1234567890" + "_-."

    @Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
    fun generateRandomEmail(@IntRange(from = 1) localEmailLength: Int, host: String = "gmail.com"): String {
        val firstLetter = RandomStringUtils.random(1, 'a'.toInt(), 'z'.toInt(), false, false)
        val temp = if (localEmailLength == 1) "" else RandomStringUtils.random(localEmailLength - 1, ALLOWED_CHARS)
        return "$firstLetter$temp@$host"
    }
}
```

Gradle file  :

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'
```