# Generating random characters and sending to text field using selenium/java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to generate random characters  - may be string or symbols or just random numbers sometimes for my test.

Example strings: Anything within A-Z, or from 0-9, 0r speacila characters such as @#$%^&&.  May be 3 or 4 words. I should be able to choose what to send.

These will be sent to a text field to test.

Right now the code I use just generates random number (Example : 7dc53df5-703e-49b3-8670-b1c468f47f1f) which doesn't make sense all the time.

Is there any better way to implement this? How can I control what I want to send.

My code:

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        waitAndClickElement(textTitle);
        sendKeysToWebElement(textTitle, uuid);
```

Comment: I am open to any good and practical options. May be something that makes sense or that I can modify in a way that I get the type of string that I require.

Comment: @Mohan `generates random number` and `doesn't make sense`; can you update the question with an example the type of _character sequence_ you are trying to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to generate random string with exact length of 10 character in one of my project.
I used this method :

```
public static String generateString() {
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        uuid = uuid.substring(0, Math.min(uuid.length(), 10));
        System.err.println(uuid);
        return uuid;
    }
```

Though there are multiple ways you can generate random strings.

I'm giving some of the references for you.

[Alpha-numeric-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)
[string-with-a-z-and-0-9-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536566/creating-a-random-string-with-a-z-and-0-9-in-java/20536597)
[java-random-string](http://www.baeldung.com/java-random-string)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out and mark it as answer if this is the best way for me :)

Comment: Marking it as answer because the links provided helped me to learn about apache class and generate strings that i required.