# How to create permanent method for random email in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I create a random email method in selenium but would like to know how to create a permanent method for the same in the Selenium web driver, so it will save time in testing.

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
    Random randomEmail = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomEmail.nextInt(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("username" + randomInt + "@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own random string generator like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20536566/creating-a-random-string-with-a-z-and-0-9-in-java):

```java
protected String getSaltString() {
        String SALTCHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        StringBuilder salt = new StringBuilder();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (salt.length() < 10) { // length of the random string.
            int index = (int) (rnd.nextFloat() * SALTCHARS.length());
            salt.append(SALTCHARS.charAt(index));
        }
        String saltStr = salt.toString() + "@gmail.com";
        return saltStr;

    }
```