# Encode string to base32 string in Java

Tags: java, base32

Just like the title says, I am trying to encode a string "test" into base32 string "ORSXG5A=" in Java.

All I find when searching online is classes that encodes from string to array with 32bits, but obviously that is not what I want.

Sorry for this newbie question.

Comment: If you can't find a canned Base32 converter you can find a Base64 one and modify it -- same principles only simpler.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Apache commons-codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) provides a [`Base32`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base32.html) class that does just that

```
Base32 base32 = new Base32();
System.out.println(base32.encodeAsString("test".getBytes()));
```

prints

```
ORSXG5A=
```

You can download it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec).

Comment: Thanks! Actually the .getBytes() was the only thing I needed :)

Comment: @DanieleTesta You might also need to consider the character encoding your String is in.

Answer (score 15):

As @Sotirios Delimanolis wrote it can be done using apache commons but you can also use google guava libraries. For example:

```
BaseEncoding.base32().encode("test".getBytes());
```

will return `ORSXG5A=`.

More information can be found [here](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html).