# Java: Is there any encoder which will not include forward slash during data encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, encoding

I need to pass data in encrypted format with URL like this, 
`http://localhost:8080/app/{encrypted_data}`

So, is there any encoder which will **not include forward slash(/) in encoding**?

**Please Note:** I don't want to replace '/' by another character, manually, from the encoded data.

..............................................................................................................

**Edited:** comment from **[Oleg Estekhin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541688/oleg-estekhin)** of using **Base64 URL safe Encoding** is also working fine, I'm just adding an example over here.

**EXAMPLE: Encode:**

```
String str = "subjects?_d=1";
byte[] bytesEncoded = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafe((str.getBytes()));
```

**Decode:**

```
Base64 decoder = new Base64(true);
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decode(new String(bytesEncoded));
System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes));
```

**Output:**

```
c3ViamVjdHM_X2Q9MQ
subjects?_d=1
```

Comment: To simplify your problem, you might use https://localhost:8080/app/?data={encrypted_data} to simplify your problem. Are you looking to hide the data or to authenticate whether the data has been changed?

Comment: No man, the requirement is not to use '?' or pass as URL parameter. Secondly, I'm encoding because I'm passing one URL on that {encryped_data}, which again contains some '/'.  :D

Comment: There are URL-safe Base64 variants, and most Base64 libraries provide an overloaded encode/decode methods that work with such variants. Check [iHarder Base64 URL_SAFE](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/api/Base64.html#URL_SAFE) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32

example:

[Encode string to base32 string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515479/encode-string-to-base32-string-in-java)

Comment: There is also a Base64 variant where `+` and `/` are replaced. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 . Especially in **Java 8** there is now http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html