# Randomly generate one chunk of numeric string in java

Tags: java, random

How do i randomly generate an alpha numeric string in java.

My session Id string is of the format

```
b03c0-000-5h6-7645-000000000
```

I want to randomly generate only the 4th chunk of it `(b03c0-000-5h6-****-000000000)`. retaining all the other numbers same.

Comment: possible dup - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html)

```
"b03c0-000-5h6-"+RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(4)+"-000000000";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private static final String CONST_ALPHA_NUM ="0123456789abcdef";

public static String getAlphaNumeric(int len) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(len);
    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        int ndx = (int)(Math.random()*CONST_ALPHA_NUM.length());
        sb.append(CONST_ALPHA_NUM.charAt(ndx));
    }
    return sb.toString();
    }

System.out.println("b03c0-000-5h6-" + getAlphaNumeric(4) +"-000000000");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.UUID;    
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(0,4) + "-000000000";
```

to be more random:

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replaceAll("-", "");
int n = (int) (Math.random() * 28);
String sessionId = "b03c0-000-5h6-" + uuid.substring(n,n+4) + "-000000000";
```

Answer (score 0):

If security is important (as I think it is with session identifiers), then I'd suggest using Java's SecureRandom. You can easily get a SecureRandom number with BigInteger:

```
BigInteger bI = new BigInteger(256, new java.security.SecureRandom())
```