# How to reset password in AD, getting an LDP OperationNotSupported error

Tags: java, active-directory, passwords, ldap

We are able to create accounts in the active directory. But for some reason we are unable to login with them. The way our system works is a user applies for an account, an admin approves it and the user is sent a temporary password to login with. 
We think it may have to do with the permissions of the user but are not quite sure. Our code is extensive but here is some of our code and **console** log:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 53 - 0000052D: SvcErr: DSID-031A120C, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0
```

We are using the same random password generator listed in this previous post:

[How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

**Java**

```
RandomPassword randPass = new RandomPassword(11);
String temporaryPassword = randPass.nextString();
Attribute password = new BasicAttribute("unicodePwd", formatPassword(temporaryPassword));
```

The `formatPassword` function comes from this article:

http://www.ramblingtech.com/will_not_perform-error-from-ad-on-password-change-using-java/

Comment: When you say you reset the password do you actually set a specific password yourselves?

Comment: We send a randomly generated temp password for them to log on initially with

Comment: Have you checked that the generated password meet the actual password complexity requirements set on the server (AD)?

Comment: We hard coded a password we knew would authenticate and it worked, have to work on our RandomPassword function. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you just totally edit this question and turn it into another? Don't do that as questions are bound to be here for a while and your question may very well help others and the comments I left for your original problem are now no longer applicable. Also, as you answered your question, that answer also no longer applies. I would suggest you create a new question for your new problem (and edit this question to get the original question back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the randomly generated password did not meet the requirements set by the AD.