# Random number and letter generators

Tags: java, random, integer

I was curious if there were methods in java to randomly generate random numbers and uppercase and lowercase letters. i am creating a password generator for a project. i am still a little new to java also.

Comment: I believe the answer is no. :)

Comment: "I was curious if there were methods" - so why didn't you use Google or the Java documentation then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Comment: If people say that there is a class called [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) in java, they are lying. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
     import java.util.Random;
```

Code is

```
    Random r = new Random();
    Integer num = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        num=r.nextInt(20000);
    System.out.println(num);
    }
```

Output : 
            12228
            8875
            10340
            8898
            11949
            8184
            14417
            17284

Comment: i guess what OP stated is _"..to randomly generate random numbers and uppercase and lowercase letters"_

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use **Math.random()** for generating random number. 
To generate a random letter you need to generate a number between 0 and 26 and then add it to the char number of 'A' or 'a'.
For example

```
int firstUppercaseIndex = (int)'A'; // for uppercase
int firstLowercaseIndex = (int)'a'; // for lowercase

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int letterIndex = r.nextInt(26); // random number between 0 and 26
    char randomLowercase = (char) (firstLowercaseIndex + letterIndex);
    char randomUppercase = (char) (firstUppercaseIndex + letterIndex);

    System.out.println("randomLowercase = " + randomLowercase);
    System.out.println("randomUppercase = " + randomUppercase);
}
```