# Store 7 Randomly generated numbers & names in an array Java

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm not sure at all how to go about this, but I want to generate 1000 randomly generated 7 digit numbers, and 5 letter names. The names could be like "FjwaS" anything, it doesnt have to be an actual name. I want to store all these values in 2 different arrays. `telephone` array, then a `name` array. I'm not sure how I should approach this at all.

Comment: Why don't you consider using HashMaps?

Comment: First, google how to generate random number, and how to generate random String.

Comment: I don't know what a HashMap is, sorry im awfully new

Comment: in a hashmap you can save your data as a couple (key,value). In your case it could be (number,name)

Answer (score 1):

Easy:

1 - create your collection

2 - iterate 1000 times

..2a - generate random values

..2b - populate your collection

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for a very basic implementation for the problem given above. Later, you can use your desired collection. Change the value of `MAX` to your desired length. The main work is done by the `randomInt()` and `randomString()` functions.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RandomDirectoryCreation
{
    static final String alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int MAX = 10;

        String[] name = new String[MAX];
        int[] telephone = new int[MAX];

        for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        {
            name[i] = randomString(5);
            telephone[i] = randomInt(1000000, 9999999);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<MAX; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Name: " + name[i] + " Telephone: " + telephone[i]);
        }
    }

    public static int randomInt(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static String randomString(int len) 
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(len);
        for( int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            word.append( alphabets.charAt(rand.nextInt(alphabets.length())));
        }
        return word.toString();
    }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Name: kBbSL Telephone: 4152479
Name: GOEat Telephone: 7473373
Name: KRBPq Telephone: 8346073
Name: yqjpu Telephone: 7553636
Name: yvRBA Telephone: 2133757
Name: ajUBg Telephone: 3826625
Name: BhBVr Telephone: 5714195
Name: AvNYB Telephone: 6179815
Name: DfsxM Telephone: 6611458
Name: gJRka Telephone: 2114751
```

References:

1. [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)
2. [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? You can use [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from Apache Commons.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = new String[1000];
        String[] telephones = new String[1000];

        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            String randomName = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5);
            names[i] = randomName;

            String randomTelephone = RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(7);  
            telephones[i] = randomTelephone;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(telephones));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had written it to generate a random string, you may change it according to your needs:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class randomWord 
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Random charp = new Random();

        String[] chars = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" ,"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "M", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

        String[] word = new String[9];

        for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
        {
            word[i] = chars[charp.nextInt(70)];
        }

        System.out.print("Your randomly generated string is: ");

        for(int i = 0; i < 9;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(word[i]);
        }


        Random number = new Random();

        System.out.println("\nRandom number: "+number.nextInt(6));

    }

}
```