# Java: Creating a by a String named Object

Tags: java, object

I would like to make a few Objects and then add them to a HastMap. I dont want to name all of these Objects by Hand so I would do it in a for Loop. Any ways to solve this ?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear?

Comment: I want to make an random named Object

Comment: Why don't you generate a random string

Comment: How can I make an Object from an String ?

Comment: I meant `Map<String,Object> map`. You create your object and a string and add to map. But why do you want to do this

Comment: I wanted to acces it via a HashMap but I want do randomly create 20 Objects

Comment: If you want to access it via a Map what should your key be? Why don't you put them in a List?

Comment: I would take the Keys 1 2 3 ...

Comment: What do you mean by *random object*? Like 1st may be of `class A` the second of `class B` and so on?

Comment: I mean by random Object an Object with a String as name

Comment: You want the variable names to be random?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a "variable variable". Java doesn't support these, but some languages, [like PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), do.  You can create a HashMap of objects with generated keys, however, like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>;
// makes a HashMap of strings to objects;
// if you want to use something else for the keys,
// you can change the first type name between the <>

map.put("key", object);
//adds an object to the HashMap for the key "key"
```

and then get the objects back from the map like this:

```
map.get("key");
//will return object
```

If you want to do this in a for loop, you'd do something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>;
String[] keys = {"foo", "bar", "food", "bard", "fooley", "barley"};
for(int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    map.put(keys[i], myObject);
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41156/3731821) is a way to generate those strings randomly.