# How to create a random output of a certain bit size in Java?

Tags: java, random, bit, secure-random

I want to create a random alpha-numeric string whose **bit** count will **always** be of size k. The size k will be something *relatively* big (varying from 128 to 2048 or more). I'm reading [this excellent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string) and I'm trying to figure something out using the `Random` and the `SecureRandom` class but to no avail.

To be more precise, the result doesn't have to be necessarily a string, it could be anything as long as it is **random** and its **bit** count is always k.

Comment: use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random))

Comment: How do you count bits of an alphanumeric string?

Comment: It's easy to generate a byte array of the right size: just use `SecureRandom.nextBytes(byte[])`. Round up to the nearest 8 bits and ignore the others if you need to...

Comment: If you already read the thread which answers your question, you should precisely explain why you still think needing to open a new question. The sentence “I'm trying to figure something out using … but to no avail” is not comprehensible considering that said thread already provides answers containing complete, working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility is the `BigInteger` constructor: `BigInteger(int numBits, Random rnd)`.

Depending on how secure you need your random bits to be, use either `Random` or `SecureRandom` for the second parameter.  There are various ways to convert a `BigInteger` to whatever final format you want.  To get a string, use `BigInteger.toString(2)` where the 2 is the radix for binary.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html?

If you need 128 bit of random Data you would need 16 bytes in Java (because a byte is 8 bit) so after (shamelessly copied from said API):

```
  SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
  byte bytes[] = new byte[16];
  random.nextBytes(bytes);
```

now you have a Array with 128 bit of random Data. For 2048 it's a byte[256];

Comment: This is probably a stupid a question but using this method always produces the exact same result, more specifically `[B@a881b5`. Is this supposed to happen? I want a different random output each time I run this.

Comment: [B@a881b5 is not the data but the ID of the Array when you do System.out.print(random) - See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html to understand. To get a String representation use java.util.Arrays.toString()

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want a specific number of bits, and cannot settle for the multiples of 8 that bytes can do, try using booleans with `SecureRandom`

```
SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
boolean bools[] = new boolean[k];
for(int x = 0; x < bools.length; x++){
 bools[x] = sr.nextBoolean();
}
```