# Generate Suitable Username & Password for File Read

Tags: java, file-io

I am looking for a solution to a problem that I am having. For the first part of my program I have to read in a file from the keyboard. This I can do, however I know nothing about generating a username and password for the file that I just read. Then, I have to write the generated password and username to another text file! Please Help! Thanks!

Here is what I have got so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Question2
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
  // Prompt for the input file name

  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String inputFileName = "Customer.txt";
  String inputText;
  File inputFile = new File(inputFileName);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);

  double total = 0;

  while (in.hasNext())
  {
     inputText = in.next();
     System.out.println (inputText);
  }

  in.close();

   }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the file?

Comment: No, Just a Program that Reads a text file, then Generates a Username and Password and Writes them to another text file.

Comment: There are some libraries that could help, check out this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really Understand it, I need to Get a Username and Password and I don't really know how this would work!

Comment: From what are you trying to generate the username and password?

Comment: I am trying to generate a Username and Password for this Text File "Customers.txt" and Write the Generated Username and Password into another text file called "Usernames.txt"