# how do i use the information from a deep link url that opens an activity in android?

Tags: java, php, android, email, mobile

I'm sending a confirmation email but i don't know how to confirm account when link is clicked?

When user click on the link i send, i want to extract the query string token and compare the token with the token in database. How do i do this?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Please read [ask] and give a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches! Have a look at the follwing approach:

Generate a unique random unique string which would be used as the `token`
for generating random string find reference in [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Store this `token` in database and send the link with this token attached to the link as `query string`.

When user click on the link you sent, extract the the query string `token` compare the token with the token in database.

If the token matches email is validated!!

> e.g.Suppose Generated token is `5DTI72EO6SFU215DTI72EO6SFU` store it in
>   database and generate the link as
>
> `mydomain.com?action=validateemail&user=theuser&token=5DTI72EO6SFU215DTI72EO6SFU`

Don't forget to remove token from database and update the email verified status!! hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have done that so far. i guess what i'm asking is how do i extract the token? whats the process? and does it happen on the android end or php end?

Comment: Are you using java at serverside