# Omnifaces FileServlet - change Output link path from image

Tags: servlets, omnifaces

I´m using the FileServlet from Omnifaces:
http://showcase.omnifaces.org/servlets/FileServlet

It works fine and all my images appears in my webapp.
But now I would like to change the link from the image because I would like to avoid that someone enter the path from another image:

For example:
The path from one image is:
myapp/imagesservlet/mypic1.jpg

-> Someone can enter 
myapp/imagesservlet/mypic2.jpg -> and got another image.

My files are stored as:
mypic like mypic1.jpg, mypic2.jpg.....

Is there any chance to change the path and got also the correct image?

Answer (score 0):

Just use unpredictable autogenerated filenames. E.g. [imgur](http://imgur.com) also does that. This responsibility is actually beyond the OmniFaces FileServlet as all it does is just inspecting the passed-in filename and serving it up. You should change the passed-in filename to be an autogenerated one. Save if necessary the original filename somewhere else, e.g. in a SQL database, if necessary along with other metadata (content type, size, etc) so it can more efficiently be indexed and searched.

How to autogenerate a random string in Java is already covered in this Q&A: [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)