# Version 4 UUID shortening

Tags: java, uuid

(http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) The documentation for UUID says :

**For UUID version 4, clock sequence is a randomly or pseudo-randomly generated 14-bit value.**

**For UUID version 4, the node field is a randomly or pseudo-randomly generated 48-bit value.**

So, is it ok to grab random octets from a Version 4 UUID if I am looking for a randomly generated String of length 12 in java?
I understand the chances of collision (duplicates) are higher but would it be a decent way to generate random strings?

Comment: If you're looking to generate random strings, there are much better ways than using a uuid.

Comment: like what? can you name a few methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string