# Generate a new string

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe

So I have code that when you press the mouse it will generate some random code in a text box, then when enter is hit, it is suppose to clear said textbox and replace is with a new random string but it just picks the same random string. E.g. I click the mouse and "hps" is generated, I click enter and "hps" is generated again. Is there a way to get a new string from my generator?

```
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            RandSt string = new RandSt(); 
            textField_tf.setText(string.randStr());
            }
```

Comment: Show your `RandSt()` method.

Comment: what is the code inside RandSt.randStr() ?

Comment: I've added it :)

Comment: Move your static class attribute `chosen` into the randStr() method (as a method variable) and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`chosen` is not reset after generating a `String`. A very simple solution would just be to add this one line at the start of your method:

```
chosen = "";
```

I would advise however, to use a completely different method, for example the one explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: You noticed that he is using Java, right? - Your advise wont compile;)