# How to generate a random String of 6 chars in Java

Tags: java

I need to write a constructor which will generate a random 6 length char. i've used : `code=UUID.randomUUID();`

and i thought of using :

```
if (code.length() != 6 ) {
 code=UUID.randomUUID();
 }
```

but there is an error which says method lenght() is undefined for type UUID. What else can i do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string

Comment: You haven't actually initialized code before calling code.length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 1):

Try using RandomStringUtils from org.apache.commons.lang3.
You can use RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(6) then

Answer (score 1):

Go with Carlos's answer, as it's a better way to get a random `String` of length 6 than using a `UUID`, but I wanted to let you know why you're seeing that error.

`UUID.randomUUID()` returns a instance of the [class `UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).  It does not have a `length` method.

If you want to treat it as a `String`, you must first call `.toString()` on it, i.e. `String code = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

Now that it is a `String`, you can use the `length` method.

Comment: That's great! Here is a guide on what to do if [someone answers your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and you find it helpful.

Comment: For my own curiosity, did you try the answer from @Carlos at all?