# Generate a random string in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to generate a 6 character random string on every compilation of a program in Java.

For example: AXFGCD, GDGXSD, PLRSFX, GLTSDL

```
public class generate{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        generate();
    }

    string word = "";
    string Characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    void generate(int x){
        if (x==7) return;

        int time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 33; //to generate time in mili second
        word += characters.charAt(time);
        System.out.println(time);
        return generate(++x);
    }
}
```

output is

```
A,AX,AXF,AXFC,AXFCG,AXFCGA
```

but I want direct 6 digit word

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS And also `string` is not a type.

Comment: why are you using recursion?

Comment: And to be pedantic - though I'm sure you don't care - this is generated at run time and not compile time.

Comment: @rohitjoshi9023 Do not edit a question with a code fix. If the code is broken somehow, raise that as a comment or as an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 2):

This was written in Notepad++ as I currently dont have any IDE available, I hope this compiles and if it does it should work :)
If you want to use uppercase characters simply edit the for loop!

```
public class generate{

    private static char[] characters;
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        characters = new char[26];
        int index = 0;
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            characters[index++] = c;
        }
        System.out.println(generate());
    }

    static String generate() {
        String word = "";
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++) {
            word += Character.toString(characters[random.nextInt(characters.length)]);
        }
        return word;
    }
}
```

Edit: using your code!

```
public class generate{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        generate();
    }

    string word = "";
    string Characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    void generate(int x){
        if (x==7) {
            System.out.println(word);
            return;
        }

        int time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 33; //to generate time in mili second
        word += characters.charAt(time);
        return generate(++x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is achieving your purpose. Your problem is that you are "logging" your steps by printing them in your method (Also, there are errors like `string`, calling your `generate` funciton incorrectly, but since you gave us the output I guess you fixed it at some point).

If you just do this:

```
public class generate{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        generate(0);
        System.out.println(word); // Here word is complete

    }

    String word = "";
    String Characters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    void generate(int x){
        if (x==7) return;

        int time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 33; //to generate time in mili second
        word += characters.charAt(time);
        return generate(++x);
    }
}
```

it will work. Alternatively, to print your `word` in your function, you could've use an iterative approach:

```
void generate(){
    for (int i = 6; i --> 0;) {
        int time = System.currentTimeMillis() % 33; //to generate time in mili second
        word += characters.charAt(time);
    }
    System.out.println(word);
}
```