# Sort vs OrderBy - performance impact

Tags: performance, hibernate, sorting, jpa, sql-order-by

In addition to jpa's `@OrderBy` which is ordering elements on SQL level, hibernate provides `@SortComparator` and `@SortNatural`, which are sorting elements after loading from db.

1. Which one is better when it comes to performance?
2. If `@OrderBy` is better, why would anyone use the other option, as it is not even a jpa standard?

Comment: I have some (not Java) code that explicitly orders on the client - this reduces temp table spill on the SQL Server box for some particular large queries. In this case since the sort is not able to reduce the result set and the result is loaded entirely into memory, moving the sort from the DB into a memory sort was a net performance / resource reduction (well, resource transfer) gain in a particular situation. Most people probably never run into this..

Comment: @Andronicus With regards to your question about `@PathVariable` (I didn't have chance to answer before you deleted it), you can use any type provided that you [register a custom PropertyEditor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-property-editor)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, @Michael

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

First, @SortComparator and @SortNatural are not sorting elements after loading them from the DB, but sorting them during their insertion. So the Elements are sorted in memory.

When using @OrderBy(COLUMN_NAME ASC) Hibernate sorts the Elements of the Collection, when the Elements are loaded from the DB by executing the Select-Statement with ORDER BY.

I measured the performance for @SortNatural and @OrderBy(clause = "random_string ASC".
Storing and Loading of 200k random strings with a length of eigth characters.
(The used code is down below.)

**The results are:**

Storing data with @SortNatural:

1. 472 seconds
2. 424 seconds

Loading data with @SortNatural:

1. 2,6 seconds
2. 1,7 seconds
3. 1,7 seconds
4. 3,0 seconds
5. 1,2 seconds

Storing data with @OrderBy

1. 431 seconds
2. 413 seconds

Loading data with @OrderBy

1. 3,3 seconds
2. 3,3 seconds
3. 3,0 seconds
4. 3,5 seconds
5. 4,8 seconds

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateTest</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        
        <property name="conection.pool_size">1</property>
        
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**ClassWithStringCollection**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="class_with_string_collection")
public class ClassWithStringColloction{
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private int id;

@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="random_strings")
@Column(name="random_string")
//@SortNatural
@OrderBy(clause = "random_string ASC")
protected SortedSet<String> randomStrings = new TreeSet<String>();

public ClassWithStringColloction() {
    
}

public ClassWithStringColloction(SortedSet<String> modules) {
    this.randomStrings = modules;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public SortedSet<String> getRandomStrings() {
    return randomStrings;
}

public void setRandomStrings(SortedSet<String> randomStrings) {
    this.randomStrings = randomStrings;
}
}
```

**main**

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                            .addAnnotatedClass(ClassWithStringColloction.class)
                            .addAnnotatedClass(RandomString.class)
                            .buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {

            long timeBefore;
            long timeAfter;
            long elapsed;
    
            SortedSet<String> randomStrings = new TreeSet();
            ClassWithStringColloction classWithSC = new ClassWithStringColloction(new TreeSet());
            
            //performance measurement propagating data to DB
            
            RandomStringGenerator randStringGen = new RandomStringGenerator(10);
            String randomString = "";
            
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(classWithSC);
            classWithSC = session.find(ClassWithStringColloction.class, 0);
            randomStrings = classWithSC.getRandomStrings();

            timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
                
                randomString = randStringGen.nextString();
                randomStrings.add(randomString);
                session.update(classWithSC);
                if (i % 100 == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
                }
            }
            
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsed = timeAfter - timeBefore;
            System.out.println("Time for storing 200000 String:" + elapsed + " ms");
            
            
            //Performance measurement for loading stored data.
            session = factory.getCurrentSession();
            
            session.beginTransaction();
            timeBefore = System.currentTimeMillis();
            classWithSC = session.get(ClassWithStringColloction.class, 0);
            randomStrings = classWithSC.getRandomStrings();
            System.out.println(randomStrings.first());
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            
            timeAfter = System.currentTimeMillis();
            elapsed = timeAfter - timeBefore;
            System.out.println("Time for loading 200000 Strings:" + elapsed + " ms");
            
            System.out.println("Done");
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.close();
        
    }

}
```

**RandomStringGenerator**
1.Answer of
[How to generate a random alpha-numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 0):

reference: https://thoughts-on-java.org/ordering-vs-sorting-hibernate-use/

Use OrderBy, if the function is frequently called.

Use Sort, if you want to load all of data to memory and you manually manage it.