# Multiple sc.nextLine(); to run one after the other, but need to run if/else statements

Tags: java

How do I check if scanner input is blank and assign a variable to the blank string? Overwriting the initial String?

Tried the following code and it does not work.

```
System.out.print("Username: ");

    String username = sc.nextLine();

    int u1nameLength = username.length();

    if (u1nameLength == 0) {

        String username = "Dude"; //generate replacement username

    }

    System.out.print("Phone Number: ");

    String phoneNumber = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Define "does not work". What is the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to reassign the variable, not redeclare it

```
if (username.isEmpty()) {
   username = "Dude"; //generate replacement username
}
```

Comment: Yes I should not have written String at the beginning. Removed it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. What is the best way to generate a string of about 10 random lowercase letters to become username, instead of using predefined "Dude"?

Comment: @JavaNoob to generate random string you can refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string).