# Textview text not showing when using tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

When am using

```
android:text="Lorem Ipsum"
```

the text is just showing normally on the textview but when am using

```
 tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
```

its not showing anything.

I have added the namespace for tools, what might be the problem?

Here is the name space

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tools:text is used only for viewing the sample view of the layout in preview. android:text actually sets the text to the TextView. You need to set the text programmatically by textView.setText("your text") or change tools namespace to android.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to use textView.setText and set text that has been generated randomly

Comment: Or using android:text to set text generated randomly

Comment: Yes, you need to create random number and convert it to string. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41156/10921974 textView.setText((new RandomString()).nextString())