# Generate 5 random Strings and add them to a Set in Java

Tags: java, string, random, set

I am a beginner in Java and have the following issue.

How can I generate 5 random strings and add them to a `Set`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 7):

First, let's create the set:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Now, let's generate 5 random strings. There are many ways to do this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string) is an answer about it. But since you did not ask for a specific length, let's proceed with this:

```
String randomStr = Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random()));
```

Now, let's repeat the random generation 5 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    set.add(Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random())));
}
```

Now, the problem is that this does not guarantee the set will have 5 random strings, as we may have similar ones. To ensure that, we should do:

```
while (set.size() < 5) {
    set.add(Long.toHexString(Double.doubleToLongBits(Math.random())));
}
```

The code above will continue generating random strings until the set contains at least 5. I'm not checking if it already contains the string because a Set, by definition, **contains no duplicate elements**. So, adding a duplicate won't increase the size.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
        Random random = new Random();
        while (set.size() != 5) {
            set.add(String.valueOf((char) (65 + random.nextInt(26))));
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
[D, X, L, M, N]
```

**Notes:**

1. `Random.nextInt(n)` generates an `int` from 0 to n-1 where `n` is an `int`. Therefore,  `65 + random.nextInt(26))` will generate a number from `65` to `90`.
2. `String.valueOf(c)` converts `c` into a `String` where `c` is a `char`.
3. The ASCII value of `A` is `65` and that of `Z` is `90`. So, `((char)65)` will be printed as `A`.

Answer (score 2):

## UUID

You can use [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) values for your random strings.

```java
Set<String> strings = IntStream.range(0, 5).boxed()
        .map(i -> UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Output:

```
[174686cc-f1e6-4532-944f-de5a85fa5979, 0151b604-93fa-41cf-8ca8-e872c29e261f, 030c6524-c8cb-4c32-a17b-6189a3a167d5, 3e99e7fd-f143-4af6-bcfc-9b968e9397c9, 11099e22-3c05-45e6-b989-2a3c62acaa15]
```

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the number values of Unicode Characters to create a string, the [Java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class is used to randomly generate a number:

### Code

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Set<String> randomStrings = new HashSet<>();//create the set
    Random random = new Random(); //this creates a random number

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) { //loop 5 times
        String generatedString = random.ints(60, 122)//(min value, max value) 
                  .limit(10) //sets the string length to 10 characters
                  .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                  .toString();
        randomStrings.add(generatedString); //add the generatedString to the Set
    }

    //print contents of the Set
    for(String s: randomStrings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
pflmmE[jCu
ogofehE<XS
BFbqtHnE_O
Qvu@IDJcI=
Al>BvaLZ@[
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (out of many possibilities).  Note that this could be condensed into a few statements but then it would be difficult to explain with comments.  First, let's get the easiest one done.

```
        Random r = new Random(23);
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            stringSet.add(Integer.toString(r.nextInt()));
        }

        stringSet.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Yep! Numbers have been converted to Strings.  You didn't specify what type of strings.

Moving on...

```
        Random r = new Random(23);
        Set<String> stringSet = new HashSet<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // use a Stringbuilder to build it.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // length of string between 6 and 10 inclusive
            int len = r.nextInt(5)+6; 

             // now build the string
             while (len-- > 0) {    
                // generate a character from 'a' to 'z' inclusive
                char c = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a'); 
                sb.append(c);
            }

            // and it to the set
            stringSet.add(sb.toString());
        }

        // print them.
        for (String s : stringSet) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
```

This run printed

```
sefmjkzket
qfjklm
dxocur
mldkzcmv
ivqrynsspu
```

Your output could be different (they are random).

Note that the building of the string  uses integers from 0 to 25 inclusive.  Since the lower case letters are sequential, you get `a` to `z` by just adding `a` to each number.  One could also just index randomly into a string of letters like so:

```
String alphabet = "abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz";
index = r.random(26); //0 to 25
char c =alphabet.charAt(index);
```

As was stated, there are many ways to do this.

Here's a final demo using Streams.  The strings are of a different nature.

```
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijlmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Set<String> strings = Stream.generate(() -> 1)
                .map(z -> alphabet.substring(r.nextInt(5),
                        r.nextInt(10) + 10))
                .distinct().limit(5).collect(Collectors.toSet());


        strings.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Print them

```
cdefghijl
abcdefghij
defghijlmnopqrs
cdefghij
cdefghijlmnopqrs
```

Answer (score 1):

## Alphabet

The solution with using alphabet:

```java
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int stringLength = 10;

Set<String> strings = IntStream.range(0, 5)
        .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, stringLength)
                .mapToObj(j -> Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(new Random().nextInt(alphabet.length()))))
                .collect(joining()))
        .collect(toSet());
```

Output:

```
[XBZPISNKHR, EBAGPRHQNX, GOCZEBGRFC, YRTQZFQNQJ, DVSUXWEITU]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to make random strings but I don't think it'll be easy tho I've never tried. Also I don't fully know what you mean by a set but I think you mean combine the strings to make a sentence? If that's the case just do this.

```
String str = "blah ";
String str2 = "ughhh ";
String str3 = "pshh ";
String together = str + str2 + str3;
System.out.println(together);
```

output

```
blah ughhh pshh
```