# Random unique alpha numeric string in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to generate a string mix of numbers-capital and small characters
but they should be unique with a specific length
Is there any algorithm or library in java to generate unique strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Comment: Generating a random string is straightforward, but guaranteeing uniqueness can be a problem. You could put the String's into a Set and check after each generated string. Then put the new unique string into the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache common lang utils is a great library for creating random numbers and many more useful stuff.

You can create a random string with letters and numbers as follows.

1 Get the dependency.
In gradle it is -

```
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3'
```

2 import randomutils

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
```

3 Generate random string of size 8 with letters = true and numbers = true

```
RandomStringUtils.random(8, true, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] array = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm".toCharArray();
        String randomString = null;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++;) {
            randomString += "" + array[0 + (int)(Math.random() * ((10 - 0) + 1))];
        }
    System.out.println("Your string is: " + randomString);
    }
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Note: I didn't have time to actually test it but you get the concept hopefully.