# Can we generate multiple random strings as per regex /^[0-9A-F]$/

Tags: java

Can we generate multiple random strings as per regex /^[0-9A-F]$/

I have written the below code, is there any better way to generate it, please do not use any lib, use only java API

```
public static void printRandomStrings(int numOfStrings){
  
    Random random = new Random();
    char[] chars = {'A','B','C','D','E','F'}; // 6 characters
    
    for(int i=0;i<numOfStrings;i++){
      
      String randomString = "";
      
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
        
          int choice = random.nextInt(2); // 0 -1
          
          if(choice == 1){
            randomString= randomString+generateRandomInt(random);
          }else{
            randomString= randomString+generateRandomChar(random,chars);
          }            
        }
      
        System.out.println(randomString);
    }        
  }      
  
  public static int generateRandomInt(Random random){
    return random.nextInt(10);
  }
  
  public static char generateRandomChar(Random random,char[] chars){
    int charIdx = random.nextInt(6);
    return chars[charIdx];
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? What are your criteria? (speed (don't use java), readability, ...)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string

Comment: Your method always generates 4-character strings. Is that part of the requirement?

Comment: Also, note a major flaw in your code is that the six characters 'A' to 'F' have equal chance of appearing as the ten characters '0' to '9'. Because they are fewer, they will be over-represented in your random strings.