# How to generate Random number in feature file

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I need to generate Random random in input fields so from feature how do I generate Random number which is like US124467895

To generate Random number from feature file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate a random alpha-numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107/how-to-generate-a-random-alpha-numeric-string)

Answer (score 0):

```
String valueToField = "LU" + RandomStringUtils.randomNumeric(10);
```